# Редактор шаблона html, css, js

Tags: редактор

Необходимо подсветить теги в редакторе с полем `textarea` при редактировании `html`, `css` и `js`. В идеале хорош был бы js, который можно было бы просто подключить к `textarea`. Где взять готовое решение?

Comment: имеете ввиду что-то вроде [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)?

Comment: @Grundy нет, мне не нужен визуальный редактор :)

Comment: тогда опишите подробнее, что именно вам нужно, возможно примеры, или картинки

Comment: @Grundy как это icecoder.net  но по проще, мне всего лишь подсветка синтаксиса нужна

Comment: тогда скорее всего подойдет [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/)

Comment: @Grundy как я понял с textarea оно не дружит

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly